# ajax call returning undefined how to fix this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following function

```
function checkIfUserExist(userName){
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/test/checkUserName/",
        data : "userName=" + userName,
        success : function(data) {
            return data;

        }
    });

}
```

I am trying to call it from another function

```
$('#userName').blur(function() {
    alert ( checkIfUserExist($('#userName').val()) );
}
```

every time i am getting `undefined` in the alert box. but it should show me the return value in the alert box.

how to fix  this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot return value from ajax call like this. Because ajax is asynchronous process, it will not wait for the success event to happen. If you want to do so, you should try synchronous ajax.
something like this

```
function checkIfUserExist() {
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test/checkUserName/",
    async: false
}).responseText;
}
```

But it is not a good thing to do. It will freeze the browser as well. The good thing you can do is to catch the Success event of ajax and do thing accordingly

Comment: synchronous ajax is usually a bad idea - it will block the whole ui while waiting for a response

Comment: what is the use of `ajax` ? if you make it `sync`??

Answer (score 1):

Thats correct behavior, because ajax is async.

To reach your goal you need [Jquery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$('#userName').blur(function() {
    $.when( 
        checkIfUserExist($('#userName').val())
    )
    .then(function( data ) {
        alert( data );
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error. - Syntax error on token ";", ) 
  expected

Comment: @LynAs, my bad, sorry, fixed

Comment: its not doing anything

Comment: I think you forgot to mention i have to change ajax code as well. return $.ajax({ .... its working now thanks

Answer (score -1):

Don't return the value from the ajax, since this is an asynchronous call, your `alert` will be called before the success and the result will always be `undefined`

alert the output with in your `success` callback.

```
function checkIfUserExist(userName){
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/test/checkUserName/",
        data : "userName=" + userName,
        success : function(data) {
            alert( data );

        }
    });

}
```

and just call the function here

```
$('#userName').blur(function() {
    checkIfUserExist($('#userName').val());
}
```

Comment: Fixes the code, but doesn't explain the fundamentals of asynchronous JS (aka, the *reason* OP's code isn't working.)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes I was explaining it in my answer while your were down voting this answer

Comment: i think you mean undefined, not null

Comment: @zzlalani: It still doesn't mention the fact AJAX is asynchronous, which is at the core of the issue,

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the data be in json format?

```
data: { "userName": userName }
```

Also, consider using the "done" function instead of success. That should help with the asynchronous nature of the call.